# Saving a 2-dimensional Sting Array in a .txt file and load from it

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, save

I want to save a 2-dimensional String Array in a .txt file and load it from it in my app. The Array should be editable and expandable in the app. I am not really experienced with BufferedWriter, BufferedReader, FileInputStream and FileOutputStream and things like this.
I have problems with this code: The BufferedWriter and BufferedReader throws a NullPointerException and I don't know why. Or does everyone know a possibillity to do this with FileInputStream and FileoutputStream?

```
public String path = 
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyFile";
File dir = new File(path);
    if(!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }
File file = new File(path + "/savedFile.txt");

public static void Save(File file, String[][] list)
{
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try
    {
        writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    }
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    try
    {
        try
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++)
                {
                    builder.append(list[i][j]+"");
                    if(j < list.length - 1)
                        builder.append(",");
                }
                builder.append("\n");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            writer.write(builder.toString());
            writer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    }
}


public static String[][] Load(File file)
{
    BufferedReader reader = null;

    try
    {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    String test;

    String[][] array  = new String[4][2]; //the indexs are for a specific example; it should be expandable, but I solve that myself

    String line;
    int row = 0;
    try
    {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] cols = line.split(",");
            int col = 0;
            for (String c : cols) {
                array[row][col] = c;
                col++;
            }
            row++;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
    return array;
}
```

Comment: Did you ask for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission? Here you have more info on how to write to a file on android: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html

Comment: `if(!dir.exists()) {
        dir.mkdirs();
    }`. Change to `if(!dir.exists()) {
        if(!dir.mkdirs()) return;
    }`. Add a Toast if it returns to inform the user. It will return! ;-).

Comment: You should first tell how your txt file looks like if you wrote that array to it. You let us guess what you have in mind.

Comment: @jonathanrz yes I have the permission in my manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem would be with the scope of variables in multiple braces you've used. try this code:

```
    public static void Save(File file, String[][] list) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
            builder.append(list[i][j] + "");
            if (j < list.length - 1) {
                builder.append(",");
            }
        }
        builder.append("\n");
    }

    try {
        Writer writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        try {

            writer.write(builder.toString());
        } finally {
            writer.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test it tomorrow. I go sleep now. But how is the load method looks like because there was a nullpointerexcepzion too